# issue with meson installaion

Tags: python, python-3.x, meson-build

I am trying to install meson on my linux host. As i am not root user , 
So i have to try with --user argument for installing meson as per following source :-

`https://mesonbuild.com/Getting-meson.html`

Command :- `pip3 install meson`

I am facing following issue :-

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/grid/common/pkgsData/python-v3.7.2/Linux/RHEL6.0-2013-x86_64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Flask_Bootstrap-3.3.7.1-py3.7.egg/EGG-INFO/requires.txt'
  Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I also tried below steps to resolve this :-

```
python3 -m venv envsource ./env/bin/activate 
source ./env/bin/activate
Error :- `Badly placed ()'s`.
```

Could you please hlep! Thanks.

Comment: You don't have permissions to write to that path.
You can setup a virtual env to install the package(recommended) or you can install to user folder(you need to ask for permissions to write) or install it as root

Comment: Yes,i tried them. I have updated my question. But no luck

Comment: Have you tried "pip3 install --user meson" ?

Comment: yes, i tried. But same issue with --user as well,

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you have squashed two command lines into one since it doesn't look correct: *python3 -m venv envsource ./env/bin/activate*. It should work with:

```
$ python3 -m venv env
$ source ./env/bin/activate
(env) $
```

- where *env* is the name of environment (also dir. name) at your choice, and you'll see this name in brackets when it's activated.

BTW, according to [user manual](https://mesonbuild.com/Getting-meson.html#installing-meson-with-pip), you should install with

```
$ pip3 install --user meson
```

and not forget to add **~/.local/bin** to PATH.